# How can I calculate time spent on status between 0900 and 1700?

Tags: google-sheets

I have start dates with times and end dates with times tracking when work was entered into a status and when it was completed. I'd like to know how many working hours were spent doing the task.

For example:

| Start Date | End Date | Working Hours (Time Spent between 9 AM - 5 PM) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8/1/2022 10:03 AM | 8/5/2022 4:43 PM | ? |
| 8/8/2022 9:03 AM | 8/10/2022 3:34 PM | ? |
| 8/10/2022 11:13 AM | 8/15/2022 4:57 PM | ? |

I'd like to know how many hours were spent working between 9 AM and 5 PM, excluding weekends and public holidays.

How can I do this calculation in Google Sheets?

Comment: Please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]. P.S. The use the HTML/CSS doesn't look to be related to what is being asked, also it's not clear why the Google Apps Script tag was included in the title and as tag as it was not mentioned in the question body.

Comment: In addition, please post a link to a spreadsheet with some data already entered in Cols A and B *as well as* the expected values for those rows hand-entered in Col C (rounded to the degree that you'd like them rounded). The more you provide, the higher the chances that a volunteer contributor here will be willing to put in the additional time to help you.

Answer (score 1):

**Try:**

```
=(NETWORKDAYS(A2,B2)-1)*("5:00 PM"-"9:00 AM") +IF(NETWORKDAYS(B2,B2),MEDIAN(MOD(B2,1),"5:00 PM","9:00 AM"),"5:00 PM") -MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS(A2,A2)*MOD(A2,1),"5:00 PM","9:00 AM")
```

Drag down to column.

**Result:**

[image]

Using `NETWORKDAYS()` function to only count the working days excluding weekends, then multiply it by the number of hours between 9AM and 5PM.

This will return a number which is in a form of the total number of days. You then format the cell to **Duration**.

**To format the cell:**

- Highlight the cells -> Then on the menu click **Format** -> **Number** -> **Duration**

### Final Result:

[image]

**References:**

- [NETWORKDAYS()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092979?hl=en)
- [Get Work hours between dates](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-work-hours-between-dates-and-times)

Comment: Perfect!! Tks!!